# Xamarin forms application crashing in release mode if any exceptions occur

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin Forms application freezes whenever any exception occurs. I have created an exception handler as well to handle the exceptions but whenever I face an exception from the API end it automatically crashes the application. This only happens in Android and not in iOS.

Here's the code for the exception handler -

```
 public async Task<bool> HandleExceptionAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            if (exception.GetType().Name == nameof(UnauthorizedException) ||
                exception.Message.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("refresh token has expired") ||
                exception.Message.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("invalid refresh token"))
            {
                //await loginFacade.LogoutAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else if (exception.GetType().Name == nameof(NoInternetConnectionException))
            {
                HandleNoInternetException();
            }
            else if (CheckIfLoggable(exception))
            {
                Log.Error(exception, string.Format(Common.Constants.LoggingFormats.ExceptionWithUserDetails, _userContext.Serialize(), exception));
            }
            else
            {
#if !DEBUG
                try
                {
                    //await emailManager.SendFeedbackEmail(exception);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
#endif
            }

            return true;
        }

        private bool CheckIfLoggable(Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.Message.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("not found".ToLowerInvariant()) ||
                exception.Message.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("BadInternetConnectionException".ToLowerInvariant()) ||
                exception.GetType() == typeof(NullReferenceException) ||
                exception.GetType() == typeof(OperationCanceledException);
        }

        private void HandleNoInternetException()
        {
            if (Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity.NetworkAccess != Xamarin.Essentials.NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
            }
            Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
        }

        private void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Essentials.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity.NetworkAccess != Xamarin.Essentials.NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
```

I have tried logging it and then removed the buggy codes which caused the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to recover from exceptions that happen during UI drawing or events, using a global exception handler.

- Use try-catch in every UI class, both in constructor, and in all event handlers (e.g. a button handler).

IMHO it’s a major PITA of Xamarin. But that is the way it is.

Even then, low level exceptions inside Xamarin code or graphics code can
crash app.

- Isolate the problem manually. Print statements, breakpoints, commenting out different code. All are sometimes necessary debugging.