# How to display a popup to the user if the app were to crash?

Tags: c#, maui

I want to be able to display a DisplayAlert after an unhandled exception.

Wrote a method and subscribed it to UnhandledException event in MauiProgram.cs

```
public async static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
    bool Terminating = e.IsTerminating;
    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Something went wrong!", "OK");
    Console.WriteLine($"\nUnhandled Exception occurred: *{exception}*\nTERMINATING?:{Terminating}\n");
}

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
```

This is what I had in mind whilst trying to implement this idea, but the program doesn't display the DisplayAlert but the console message appears.

Comment: once the `UnhandledException` is reached the OS is already shutting down your app.  Showing any UI at that point is not possible.  You need to handle exceptions closer to their point of origin if you want to be able to display UI to the user

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694033/199364 for my description of what to do instead.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - your answer there is for Xamarin, does it apply to Maui also?

Comment: Thank you for asking for that clarification. AFAIK, yes. (Porting my code from XForms, so I had already done this manually for each class that I needed to debug.) My understanding is that the interop between c# and underlying platform code is essentially the same. I hope to eventually dive into Maui source code deeply enough to devise a way to write this logic once, then use code generation to make this automatic for UI classes. Just adorn each one with a meta attribute, similar to `[ObservableProperty]`. But that is months away.

Comment: I should explain why Console.WriteLine works: that goes to debug output (VS Output pane, when attached), and can be done as long as the debugger connection hasn't been lost by the dying app. (I have not yet experimented with Maui's global exception handler, to determine whether it can recover from some situations that XForms can't. Regardless, its primary purpose has historically been to log information while an app is dying. When user starts app again, you can write code to send to a server, or to ask user if they want to email a bug report, in which you include exception details.)